# Function scope with AJAX [jQuery]

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've got a function that adds or removes a class when clicked:

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
// do stuff
});
```

However, I am also loading stuff with AJAX. When I load the AJAX, the click event does not work with the newly loaded content.

Is there a way I can get the function to work globally, rather than have to repeat it within the callback? Would it be something like `change` or `live`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', 'button', function(){
    // do stuff
});
```

This works with newly added elements. You can change `document` to whatever parent element you have.

Comment: Thanks. What is jQuery doing differently to make this happen?

Comment: @tmyie - I'm not sure how exactly they achieve this effect but you can check their [source code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js) for that. (line 4785)